# argument of sequence of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

How can I find a sequence $z_n = x_n+iy_n \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{ 0\}$ with its limit $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{ 0\}$ such that $arg(z_n) \rightarrow -\pi$ and $arg(z) = \pi$? where $arg(z) = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What's your range on $\arg(z)$? To me, it seems like an argument of $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are the same thing. Usually you'd only have one of them inclusive like $-\pi < \arg(z) \le \pi$

Comment: $e^{ix}=e^{i(x+2\pi n)}$ for any integer n.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$z_n = -1 - \frac{i}{n}\to -1$$
when $n\to\infty$. You can check easily that $\arg z_n\to -\pi$ while $\arg(-1) = \pi$.